# rm() not removing object that exists

Tags: r

Sorry that I don't have code that can reproduce this, because I don't know how to reproduce it. I've tried (**edit: attempt shown below**). This is part of a large program.

```
Browse[1]> exists("startPoint")
[1] TRUE
Browse[1]> rm(startPoint)
Warning message:
In rm(startPoint) : object 'startPoint' not found
Browse[1]> startPoint
[1] 1037
```

how is this possible? 
I `load()`ed startPoint from a previously saved file, and put a browser right after that `load()`, so I'm pretty sure its some kind of scoping issue but I don't know how to isolate it.

this all takes place within a function, so it reduces to

```
myFun <- function({
#lots of code
load(file = "filethatcontainsstartpoint")
if (exists("startPoint"))
  rm(startPoint)
#lots of code
})
```

**second edit** after another comment:

I tried this, but it works fine

```
A<-B<-1
save(A,B,file = "boringfile")
rm(A)
rm(B)
testFunct <- function({browser();load("boringfile");print(A)})
testFunct()
Called from: testFunct()
Browse[1]> n
debug at #1: load("boringfile")
Browse[2]> n
debug at #1: print(A)
Browse[2]> A
[1] 1
Browse[2]> B
[1] 1
Browse[2]> rm(A)
Browse[2]> A
Error: object 'A' not found
```

As expected.
This also functions as expected if the saving is done within a function rather than in the global env.
Also I'm not sure why you consider the purpose to be relevant, but:
I have some files that contain a variable which I'd like to remove if it's contained in the file. About half the files have this variable, so I embedded a load, check existence, remove, resave within my program. I got this "not found" error when *not* browsing, then went to investigate with the `browser()`.

Don't waste any time coming up with a workaround, that's easy enough, I was just hoping to understand this specific issue if it's the case that someone just knows. I don't expect very much since I can't make a MRE work

Comment: Why are you trying to `rm` from within the browser? I admit that when I try to `rm` an object in the browser, it does seem to succeed, so I'm not really able to explain your difficulty.

Comment: because I'm getting the warning in my function, so I went to the place in the function where it happens

Comment: Ah. Then maybe you need to supply an argument such as `rm("startPoint", envir=environment(fnc_name) )`. Whether doing that (removing an object from a running function) will makes sense is not clear to me. What is now suggested is that you have not described the situation clearly.

Comment: so I need to do that within the function itself? As it is, I have a check for existence, then a removal if so. I need to refer to the environment that the function is in, within the function? I just edited it to show kind of what it looks like.

Comment: I don't see how I can answer that question since neither purpose of removing it or the programming context have been described in sufficient detail. In your question ... write code. Make a function, save it to a named Rdata object, load it and go from there.

Comment: Above, you describe "there is a browser after load", in your example, you are doing it the other way around, first browser, then load.

Comment: browsing doesn't affect the effect of `load()`, it just halts execution. For the first case if I put the `browser()` right before the load, the same thing would happen.